# No .altcoin directory being generated

Tags: bitcoin-core, altcoin-development, compiling, genesis-block

I am trying to create a genesis block for a personal play coin. I get the correct output of assertion failed. However when compiling I noticed the `./altcoin` folder is not created at all.

Answer (score 1):

The data directory (`~/.altcoin`) is created when the software is run, not when it is being compiled. Compilation has nothing to do with the datadir.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Andrew I actually was able to get the debug.log to work and create the merkle and hash with a little workaround. 

Getting a fatal error 
`ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at CBlockDiskPos(nFile=0, nPos=8)`
Wondering if you happen to have a suggestion for this?
I tried reindexing that didn't seem to make a difference, is this related to genesis not being mind?

Comment: It means your genesis block is invalid. You probably did not mine it so it does not have a valid proof of work. You actually have to mine the genesis block and make sure it has a valid PoW.

Comment: I guess my confusion lies with the fact that if with that error I can't connect the seed nodes to actually mine the block or am I looking at this wrong?

Comment: Normal miners won't be able to mine the genesis block. You have to temporarily modify your altcoin client to mine it.

Comment: Thank you that gives me an idea where to start looking, i appreciate it!